# Comentário igual #region do Visual Studio

Tags: php, visual-studio, netbeans, ide, comentários

Existe comentário igual `#region` do Visual Studio no PHP com NetBeans?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Por sorte não tem. [Isto foi um erro do C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82413/101). Mas dá para conseguir [efeito semelhante especificamente com seu editor](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqCustomCodeFolds):

```
// <editor-fold>
   Your code goes here...
// </editor-fold>
```

[Funciona com o PHPStorm](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2012/03/new-in-4-0-custom-code-folding-regions/) também.

Comment: Você não recomenda o uso de #region?

Comment: Não. Até já cheguei pensar em responder em uma pergunta que tem aqui sobre o assunto. Isto só mostra que o código está desorganizado. O `#region` foi criado p/ um propósito específico, depois descobriram q ainda ficava ruim e criaram o `partial` q resolvia melhor o problema.

Comment: Legal, vou repensar na forma que estou utilizando.