# #region é um antipattern ou um code smell?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, estilo-de-codificação, diretivas-de-compilação

O `#region` do Visual Studio ele esconde os códigos, todos falam que ele é ruim, porque ele existe? É um *antipattern* ou um *code smell*?

Comment: Até onde eu sei ele não é *exatamente* um recurso da linguagem (C#), e sim um recurso do editor. Isto é, o interpretador/compilador simplesmente ignora essa marcação. Portanto, não é nem um nem outro. Ele *pode* ser ruim do ponto de vista de usabilidade (isto é, você precisa clicar pra expandir uma região de código escondida), mas o código tá lá disponível.

Comment: Relacionado a [Are #regions an antipattern or code smell?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/53086/172464)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sim, é. Mostra que o código está grande demais, difícil demais de organizar.

Ele existe porque precisam separar código gerado pelo IDE (Visual Studio) do código que o programador deveria mexer. Perceberam o erro e criaram uma solução melhor, o [`partial`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10669/101), desta forma você separa de forma mais adequada e segura, prefira ele.

Se as classes são muito grandes provavelmente ela está fazendo coisas demais, provavelmente ela tem baixa [coesão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101). Da mesma forma que métodos não devem ter muitas linhas porque isto indica que ele está fazendo coisas demais, uma classe também não deve ser tão grande.

A maioria das vezes quando as pessoas organizam por funcionalidade mostra claramente que a classe tem funções demais.

## Formas de agrupamento

Alguns agrupam a implementação de uma interface, o que muitas vezes só tem um membro (aí fica ridículo usar `#region` mas as pessoas usam por consistência). Mesmo quando há vários membros, não há ganho. Não deixa de ser um agrupamento por funcionalidade.

Há o agrupamento do campo com propriedade ou evento com delegado. Também é agrupar por funcionalidade. Eles devem estar próximos, mas só.

Quando se organiza por visibilidade pode até ser um pouco melhor mas ainda mostra que tem coisas demais. Mas quando isto é necessário, em geral o `partial` pode ser uma saída. Nem todos gostam.

## Sem abuso

Mas esse recurso em si não melhora a qualidade do código nem faz nada adicional. Ele soluciona um problema causado pelo próprio código que dificulta a leitura do código.

Agrupar código é válido, delimitar onde eles estão é exagero.

Não é que não deva usar, não causa problemas, mas é que seu uso indica algo errado no seu código que você está querendo solucionar com isto. Fica tentador fazer errado porque existe uma "solução".

Como tudo, tem momentos para usar. Eu costumo dizer que é algo que não deveria estar na linguagem porque no fundo é um facilitador para o IDE, mesmo quando serve para *colapsar* código, então neste caso um comentário é suficiente, ainda que provavelmente usado para resolver o tal problema de código muito grande.

Mas se você me perguntam onde eu uso: em lugar algum. Eu prefiro reduzir o código ou quando não é possível mesmo, separo o que é API e o que é detalhe de implementação em arquivos separados.

Já é ruim para agrupar métodos, fica pior se usar dentro de métodos. Embora eu já ache que as pessoas costumam usar *regions* brancas dentro de métodos. Quando se costuma pular linhas em branco para separar partes de código do método, está se criando regiões e provavelmente elas não são necessárias ou indicam que o método está grande demais, mas parece ser um gosto da maioria das pessoas.

> StyleCop SA1124: you should not use regions

Minha experiência pessoal de ficar abrindo e fechando as regiões foi terrível, atrapalhava mais que ajudava. Já pedi demissão porque exigiam o uso deste recurso (ok, não foi o único motivo). Eu aprendi a pensar melhor no código quando eu vejo necessidade de uso de `#region`. E vejo com frequência. Prefiro evitar o caminho mais curto.

[Faz parte da especificação da linguagem](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55979&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Se fosse só um recurso do IDE poderia usar um comentário. No fundo o resultado é o mesmo mas o compilador tem que tratar isto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: apesar de o que você ter mencionado fazer muito sentido e não estar necessariamente errado, eu não concordo muito. Não acho que o `#region` é intrinsecamente ruim. Ele pode ser mal utilizado como qualquer outro recurso de uma linguagem. A mera existência dessa marca no código não mostra que o código está ruim. Alguém poderia utilizá-lo para separar atributos e métodos privados, protegidos e públicos, por exemplo. É uma questão de organização pessoal. Entendo que a sua colocação inicial (que você menciona o `partial`) tem uma grande validade histórica, mas a conclusão é delicada.

Comment: Em outras palavras, eu só discordo com essa frase: `"mas é que seu uso indica algo errado no seu código que você está querendo solucionar com isto"`. Isso não é necessariamente verdade. :) Ah, e sobre a sua experiência pessoal, eu também concordo. A minha também foi péssima e eu não uso (mas foi mais porque ficar abrindo e fechando regiões é um saco).

Comment: Indica, não garante. Eu falo que ele pode ser usado. Eu até mostro que separar por visibilidade é o único ponto onde tem lá sua utilidade. Mesmo assim eu preferia o jeito do C++. *Code smell* não é *code rotten*.

Answer (score -3):

O **#region** é utilizado para organizar o seu código. Em uma classe você tem atributos, getters and setters, métodos de processamento. Suponhamos que você queira organizar a sua classe em regiões para ficar melhor organizada e você possa encontrar o que você procura com mais facilidade. Você pode fazer assim:

```
public class MyClass 
{
    #region atributos
    //aqui voce coloca os atributos
    #endregion

    #region metodos
    //aqui você coloca seus métodos
    #endregion

    #region getSet
    //getters and setters
    #endregion
}
```

Ou até mais divisões, classificando seus métodos por exemplo. Assim, quando você quer trabalhar com seus métodos, pode esconder as outras regiões e trabalhar apenas com a região dos métodos.

É uma maneira de organizar seu código para ficar mais legível, organizado e fácil de desenvolver.

Comment: A pergunta não é sobre o que é o recurso, é porque ele é ruim.