# Em que momento devo instanciar uma classe?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, classes, estilo-de-codificação

Estou com dúvida em qual é o melhor momento para <del>chamar</del> instanciar uma `classe`.

Devo fazê-lo no começo, antes do construtor, no construtor ou na hora em que vamos fazer a utilização de algum método?

No exemplo abaixo crio instâncias de algumas `classe` e alguns `Datatable`, antes do meu construtor:

```
public partial class Manutenção_cliente : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
{
    consulta_bd consulta_bd = new consulta_bd();
    cadastro_bd cadastro_bd = new cadastro_bd();
    excluir_bd excluir_bd = new excluir_bd();
    controles_text control_text = new controles_text();
    DataTable cobranca = new DataTable();
    DataTable entrega = new DataTable();
    Consulta_cidade cidade = new Consulta_cidade();

    public int id_cliente, editar, chek_excluir, chek_new_cli, contador, id_end_cobranca, id_end_entrega, ck = 0, lad = 0;

    public Manutenção_cliente(int id)
    {
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Classes não são chamadas, apenas métodos são chamados. No máximo está chamando o construtor que instancia a classe e o objeto é armazenado na variável, em geral de forma indireta.

Se estiver falando de onde [declarar as variáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136279/101) que vão sustentar a instância, não há lugar certo pré-definido, é usado onde tem que usar. Pode ser na classe, pode ser dentro de um método, se seu [tempo de vida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) deve ser local.

Se vai no começo da classe, no meio, no fim, antes ou depois de alguma coisa, se vai tudo espalhado, pouco ou nada importa. É uma questão de organização e gosto. É muito comum que seja feito logo no começo, mas nem todos seguem isso, e pode haver casos onde é melhor fazer diferente.

Não há requisito técnico, a ordem de inicialização não pode ser definida dentro da classe, só dentro de métodos.

É comum agrupar todos os membros privados, depois agrupar as propriedades. Também costuma-se agrupar os membros estáticos. Tem quem goste até usar [`#region`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82413/101), mas "a maioria" prefere evitar isso.

Se precisar muita organização é provável que a classe está fazendo coisas demais.

Várias variáveis da classe `Manutenção_cliente` estão sendo inicializadas quando uma instância dessa classe é criada. Parece ser uma decisão acertada para esse caso.

Em alguns casos pode ser que alguns membros precisem ser inicializados dentro do [construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101), comum quando se precisa de uma ordem específica ou precisa inicializar outras partes das instâncias que não podem ser facilmente feitas nas variáveis (precisa de inicialização de membros posterior), ou ainda algum processamento específico. Em casos bem mais raros pode precisar inicializar em algum método "normal", mas isso é um perigo porque a classe possivelmente ficará em estado inválido.

Esse código não segue o [padrão de nomenclatura do C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31646/101). Também usa membros públicos ou pelo menos internos (visibilidade padrão), que [normalmente deve ser evitado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133924/101), mas não a todo custo, precisa saber quando fazer ou não.

Comment: "Tem quem goste até usar `#region`, mas a maioria prefere evitar isso." Porquê?

Comment: @ramaral clica no *link* que tem uma resposta que fala mais detalhadamente sobre isso.